# How do I create/edit/configure multiple PayPal Standard Payment Buttons?

Tags: ruby, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have created an ecommerce store, and I'm using [PayPal "Add to Cart" Buttons](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/) with what they call 'hosted' buttons (PayPal stores the buttons on their servers) for each of my products.

#### For reference on how they work (and why I use them):

1. You create a button(product) inside your PayPal Dashboard and you define the quantity available (most of them are 1 in my case)
2. You copy the HTML code into your website (or just copy the link)
3. The user buys the product (and the quantity falls -1)

The reason I use this setup is because my website is static, and PayPal provides the Quanity (SKU) Management - so no one can buy a product that no longer exists - even if he can access the button/link.

### My Problem

The PayPal GUI dashboard for creating buttons is very time-consuming, I would like to have the ability to edit/create etc. buttons in bulk.

I had search and search for a solution online but have found nothing.

### Possible Solution

The only thing I've recently gave some thought was the [PayPal Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/button-manager/) and the Ruby SDK in particular, but even if I've studied programming and I'm really eager to keep learning more, I don't know yet what to do in order to make the API calls.

I can't understand from their documentation and I have found zero tutorials online for such a thing.

#### Failed Solution

As I was familiar with WordPress I tried installing a plugin called [PayPal Button Manager](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-wp-button-manager) but it hasn't the ability to edit in bulk, which is what I'm trying to do.

---

All in all, I want to:

- Create, Edit, Delete, Update in bulk **PayPal Hosted Add to Cart Buttons**
- If using the Ruby API, I would much prefer doing so in a local environment

---

> I'm using Jekyll for my static site, so I'm having Ruby installed and have read multiple times that it's an 'easy' to learn language. But if you can think of something else, I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Wordpress, then you have a local database, and might end up much happier with a solution that stores quantities locally in that database, such as the WooCommerce plugin, with the following additional plugin for payment: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/

Your proposed solution of using PayPal Standard Buttons with the legacy PayPal Button Manager API .. is extremely unconventional in contrast, and would be considered a "terrible, horrible, no good, very bad" hack by most.